# JavaScript reduce returns null if array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I need the count of my objects in the array based on their type. I don't know what I'm missing here, but this is what I do:

```
myCounts = (myArray || []).reduce(function _countMembersByType(counts, member) {
  return counts[member.type === productType.GROUP ? 'groupCount' : 'individualCount']++;
}, {groupCount: 0 , individualCount: 0});
```

When `myArray` has members, `myCounts` will be `null`. Otherwise, it will be an object as `myCounts: {"groupCount":0,"individualCount":0}` as I would expect.

I'm new to JS and would appreciate any help!

Comment: You mean _When myArray does NOT have members_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your returning the result of plus 1'ing, so in the next iteration, previous or `counts` will be a number not your base object.

You need to return the whole object.

```
myCounts = (myArray || []).reduce(function _countMembersByType(counts, member) {
  counts[member.type === productType.GROUP ? 'groupCount' : 'individualCount']++;
  return counts;
}, {
  groupCount: 0,
  individualCount: 0
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj7zkseo/)

Comment: Oh I see! Dumb mistake! Thanks :)